# irrationality measure

Tags: transcendence-theory, irrationality-measure

I was reading that you can associate a measure to any given number giving you "how irrational" the given number is. I was wondering is there any irrationality measure that would tell you that the number under consideration is 100 percent irrational.

I guess what I am asking is: Can you establish that any number is irrational purely by looking at its associated irrationality measure?

Also, for numbers whose irrationality is unknown like Pi+e, is anything known about their irrationality measure?

Comment: If the number's [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) is $\ge 2$, it is irrational.

Comment: Maybe irrationals that are calculable (like Pi and E) could be defined as less irrational than those that are not. I don't even know if there is a proof that some irrationals are not calculable.

Comment: "I was wondering is there any irrationality measure that would tell you that the number under consideration is 100 percent irrational." A number is either irrational, or it isn't. There is no such thing as a number being, say, 73 percent irrational.

Comment: I appreciate the fact, but I was under the impression that there are irrationality measures that can be associated with some irrational numbers and some rational numbers, so one could not look at such a measure and say that, aha this number is 100 percent irrational.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia: Liouville_number, Irrationality_measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure):

> As a consequence of Dirichlet's approximation theorem every irrational
> number has irrationality measure at least 2.

and

> Every rational number $\frac{p}{q}$ has an irrationality measure of exactly 1.

So
$x \in \mathbb{Q} \implies \mu(x) = 1$ and
$x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \implies \mu(x) \geq 2$.

Thus, these are not just implications, but also equivalences, because let's say we know the irrationality measure $\mu(x)$ of some number $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Note that 1 < $\mu(x)$ < 2 can't happen. So if $\mu(x) = 1$, we know that $x$ cannot be irrational, thus it must be rational. And if $\mu(x) \geq 2$, then $x$ cannot be rational, thus it must be irrational. In conclusion we assert that

$x \in \mathbb{Q} \iff \mu(x) = 1$ and
$x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q} \iff \mu(x) \geq 2$.

This answers your second question. If we know the interval wherein $\mu(x)$ is, then we directly know if $x$ is rational or irrational, so if we would know, hypothetically, e.g. that $2 \leq \mu(\pi+e) < 1000$, then this would directly tell us that $\pi+e$ is irrational.

Comment: That 9 years old question seems to be on the level of a beginner in transcendence theory and irrationality measure. This is exactly where I am right now, so I will answer it on my level with the tools available to me, and hence the answer should be very useful for other beginners in this field.